# Keep React Portal on external window displayed during re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My goal for this part of the app, is that when a user retrieves information, it's displayed in an external window.  I had this working by using a separate component but if I opened a second window, the content in the first portal would disappear.  I assumed that had something to do with state. Therefore, I rewrote the parent container with useReducer and no longer reference the child component but try to use createPortal in the parent component. While the windows pop open fine, state is updated fine, the portal never renders the content the first child.  Code below.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, useReducer} from "react";
import fiostv from "../api/fiostv";
import Accordion from "./Accordion";
import "./App.css";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const initialState = []

function reducer(state, action) {
  /*
  TODO: needs a 'REMOVE' action,
  TODO: not using the open property. Use it or delete it
   */
  
  switch (action.type) {
     case "ADD":
       return [
         ...state,
         {
           win: null,
           title: action.payload.device,
           content: action.payload.data,
           open: false
          }
         ];
     default:
       return state;
   }
}

function ConfigFetcher() {
  
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  
  const [device, setDevice] = useState("");
  const [locations, setLocations] = useState(null );
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);
  const [content, setContent] = useState(null);
  const [firstDate, setFirstDate] = useState(null);
  const [secondDate, setSecondDate] = useState(null);
 
  
  async function fetchData(url){
    let response = await fiostv.get(url);
    response = await response.data;
    return response;
  }
  
  function formSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!firstDate || !secondDate) {
      fetchData(`/backups/${selectedOption}`).then(data => {
        if (!state.find(o => o.title === device)) {
          dispatch({type: "ADD", payload: {device, data}})
        }
      });
      
    }
    else {
      fetchData(`/diffs/${selectedOption}/${firstDate}/${secondDate}`).then(data => {
        if (data.includes("Error:")) {
          alert(data)
        }
        else {
          setContent(data)
        }
      });
    }
  }
  
  const createPortal = () => {
     if (state.length > 0 ) {
      const obj = state.find(o => o.title === device)
      const pre = document.createElement('pre');
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.appendChild(pre)
      const container = document.body.appendChild(div);
      obj.win = window.open('',
        obj.title,
        'width=600,height=400,left=200,top=200'
      );
      obj.win.document.title = obj.title;
      obj.win.document.body.appendChild(container);
  
      if (obj) {
        return (
          ReactDOM.createPortal(
            obj.content, container.firstChild
          )
        );
      } else {
        return null
      }
    }
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    createPortal();
  }, [state])
  
  const rearrange = (date_string) => {
    let d = date_string.split('-');
    let e = d.splice(0, 1)[0]
    d.push(e)
    return d.join('-');
  }
  
  function onDateChange(e) {
    if (content != null) {
      setContent(null);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target.name === "firstDate"){
      setFirstDate(rearrange(e.target.value));
    }
    else {
      setSecondDate(rearrange(e.target.value));
    }
  }
  
  const onValueChange = (e) => {
    if (content != null) {
      setContent(null);
    }
    setSelectedOption(e.target.value);
    setDevice(e.target.name)
  }
  
  const Values = (objects) => {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={formSubmit} className={"form-group"}>
        <fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <div className={"datePickers"}>
              <label htmlFor={"firstDate"}>First config date</label>
              <input name={"firstDate"} type={"date"} onChange={onDateChange}/>
              <label htmlFor={"secondDate"}>Second config date</label>
              <input name={"secondDate"} type={"date"} onChange={onDateChange}/>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
          {Object.values(objects).map(val => (
            <div className={"radio"}
                 style={{textAlign: "left", width: "100%"}}>
                <input type={"radio"}
                   name={val.sysname}
                   value={val.uuid}
                   checked={selectedOption === val.uuid}
                   onChange={onValueChange}
                   style={{verticalAlign: "middle"}}
                  />
                <label
                  style={{verticalAlign: "middle", textAlign: "left", width: "50%"}}>
                  {val.sysname}
                </label>
            </div>
          ))}
          <div className={"formButtons"}>
            <button type={"submit"} className={"btn-submit"}>Submit</button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    );
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData('/devicelocations').then(data => {setLocations(data)});
  }, []);
```

Comment: I guess you are not returning the portal. It should be inside render indealy. Please check this https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Comment: @KishanVikani Thanks for the reply.  I did have that working with the createPortal in a separate component.  However, I want to open a second external window.  When I do, the new content is displayed in the new external window but the old content is gone from the first external window.  I was hoping it has something to do with state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work the way I envisioned due to the nature of SPA's.  When opening a second window, the content produced by the component will always "unmount" when the new content is displayed in the new window.  The best is to have only one window open and make sure you have clean up code.  For example, when a user closes a window, have a listener that cleans up the state with a dispatch.  If the user doesn't close a window but another component is rendered, make sure a cleanup function exists in the useEffect hook to clean up any state and close the window.